# mapboxgl api access error : {"message":"Not Found"}

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm using mapbox studio to produce custom map and accessing that style in js. but I'm not able to access that style when calling api. it simply returns with {"message":"Not Found"}
I can directly access the api link through mapbox studio. In mapbox studio in styles we have map style id and api link. so i can access it using that link but when I actually use in my application it's not working.

here is the code where I'm getting error:

```
               map.addSource('parcels', {
                    "type": "vector",
                    "url": "mapbox://styles/ch*****/ci****************"
                });
```

Hoping to get some good help.
thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 3):

There are two potential causes for `Not Found` errors:

**You are looking at an area of the map where there is no data.** The Mapbox API responds with a 404 status code to indicate "no data" for vector tiles. These messages can be ignored. Try panning to an area where there is data.

**You are using the wrong access token.** Make sure you are using an access token from the account used to create the map. You can read more about Mapbox access tokens here https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-access-token

Comment: thanks for your kind response @Lucas . I figured it out and I was getting confused with style and mapid, so in api instead of calling mapid, i was using mapstyle name/id, so it was giving me error. you don't believe it took 1 week to understand this ....anyways thanks

Comment: For others, my answer here might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772538/mapbox-how-to-avoid-javascript-errors-for-tilesets-that-arent-available-at-the?rq=1