# Mapbox-gl.js logs lots of 404 errors for tiles in the browser console

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Ok, I am using Mapbox as my mapping library, I render the map layers using the tiles (geojson) uploaded to the mapbox account. [Demo here](http://jsbin.com/xatinuvoma/edit?html,js)

The map renders properly but I get lots of 404 not found errors for the source tiles.

How to get rid of these errors?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    //style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/saurabhp/cizmll8v200452sqj5c16hc55?optimize=true', // optimize=true,
    center: [-1.41, 6.32],
    zoom: 5
});

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'maine',
        'type': 'fill',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': {
              property: 'NDVI6',
                stops: [
                    [0, '#F2F12D'],
                    [1, '#EED322'],
                    [2, '#E6B71E'],
                    [3, '#DA9C20'],
                    [4, '#CA8323'],
                    [5, '#B86B25'],
                    [6, '#A25626'],
                    [7, '#8B4225'],
                    [8, '#723122']
                ]
            },
            'fill-opacity': 0.8
        },
        'source': {
            'type': 'vector',
            'url': 'mapbox://saurabhp.cizs70g1e003033lkqw0u2rjj-6kayy'
        },
       "source-layer": "ghanaTestTileset",
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapbox: How to avoid JavaScript errors for tilesets that aren't available at the current zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772538/mapbox-how-to-avoid-javascript-errors-for-tilesets-that-arent-available-at-the)

Comment: What version of mapbox-gl-js are you using? Recent versions should avoid requesting tiles that do not exist in a given source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by **mollymerp**, updating the mapbox-gl js from 0.32.0 to 0.37.0 resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to replace the default error handler, filtering out the "Not Found" message:

```
map.on('error', e => {
    // Hide those annoying non-error errors
    if (e && e.error !== 'Error: Not Found')
        console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: Though it removed few of the 404 errors, but I still see the bunch of 404 errors in the console.

Comment: it will remove error, when browser get's 404 on any resource, it logs that in console, you can't remove that, you can only catch errors which is from script. it's browser's log. ;-) you can't remove it.

Comment: So do you know the reason, why mapbox fails to download the resources, even though the source layer url is correct?

Comment: Heh, you literally copy-pasted my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772538/mapbox-how-to-avoid-javascript-errors-for-tilesets-that-arent-available-at-the/42777638#42777638 . For future reference, you should just mention that the question is a duplicate (with a link), and vote to close it (if you can).

Comment: @SaurabhPalatkar The normal reason is because there is no data in the region you're trying to download. I thought Mapbox had switched to using a different code ("No data, but no error") but maybe not.